# can Collections.unmodified be applied to a Collections.EMPTY_MAP

Tags: java, collections

```
private final Map q;
public Info()
{
    this(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}

public Info(final Map q)
{
    this.qualifiers = new HashMap(q);
}

   public Map getQ()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(q);
}
```

Do I need to use Collections.unmodifiableMap() because I saw from the JAVA Docs of EMPTY_MAP that it is Immutable?

Comment: If the Javadoc says it, then it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to use Collections.unmodifiableMap() if you want to ensure that clients of your class never modify its internal representation - or rather, if you want to ensure that a failure will occur if a client ever tries to do so.

In the case where the internal map `q` is `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` then you wouldn't need to wrap it in a call to `Collections.unmodifiableMap` because it's already unmodifiable. However you have an alternative constructor that creates `q` as a modifiable Map, and in that case you'd need to protect it before returning it.

You can also simply return a copy of `q` in which case clients could modify the returned object without modifying your class's internal state nor raising an exception.

Answer (score 2):

EMPTY_MAP is immutable but you still need to use `Collections.unmodifiableMap(q)` if `Info` has been instantiated with a map that is not EMPTY_MAP, using the second constructor...